# Why is jQuery not applying the border style?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to know why JQuery is not applying the border-bottom css property when I apply the addCLass method. It applies the colour but not the border. Why is that?
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egh7a/

Thanks.

html

```
<section class="news">
    <article>one</article>
    <article>two</article>
    <article>three</article>
    <article>four</article>
</section>
```

jQuery

```
$(".news article:last").addClass("two");
```

css

```
.news {
   border-top: 1px solid #777;
}

.news article {
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom; 10px;
   border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}

.two {
   color: red;
   border-bottom: black solid 2px; 
}
```

Comment: specificity my friend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article item takes its style from the more specific css rule.

In this case `.news article` is more specific than `.two`.

Try changing your `.two` class to `.news .two` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because the new `border` style isn't *overriding* the last one. You can use `!important` to *override* it.

```
.two {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: black solid 2px !important; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egh7a/3/)

Comment: Don't use !important if you can avoid it. It should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: If you know what you are doing, using `!important` can save you a lot of time. This is just an example how the OP can fix the issue without changing its `class` selectors.

Comment: you can add parent class before that to show how to fix the issue don't tell anybody anything which is not in standards. :)

Comment: Yes, if you know what you are doing. But what about when you suddenly need to override the !important rule? The only way to override !important is to have another rule with !important with a specificity that is higher than the first !important rule, which brings you back to square one. All recommendations point in the same direction - !important is last resort only.